# How to play big authenticated audio by howler.js

Tags: javascript, audio, howler.js

I'm trying to make an audio player using howler.js and encounter a problem with authentication.

The audio isn't public, I need to get it via an API which supports range in bytes, that means I can set start byte and end byte. I can get the data of the whole audio and create a Blob url and pass into the Howl object, but the file can be very large and this approach isn't reasonable.

Any suggestion is appreciated, even changing the API for getting audio stream.